# Show that two square matrices are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two square rational matrices such that $A^2 = B^2 = -Id$.

I want to show that $A$ and $B$ are similar. That is: I want to find a rational matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1} = B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfy $p(A) = p(B)= 0$ where $p$ is the irreducible polynomial $p(x) = x^2 + 1$.

By the structure theorem for PIDs, it follows that $A$ and $B$ are similar to the [rational-canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0\\&&0&-1\\&&1&0\\&&&&\ddots}
$$
So that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

With respect to the complex numbers, we might say the following: since $p(x)$ is factorizable with distinct linear factors over $\Bbb C$ (i.e. $p(x) = (x-i)(x+i)$), we can conclude that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ with eigenvalues $\pm i$.  Because $A$ and $B$ are rational matrices, their complex eigenvalues must come in conjugate pairs.  So, $A$ and $B$ are square of an even size $n = 2k$, and each has an eigenspace of size $k$ for $\lambda = i$ and $\lambda = -i$.